# Possibility of EMVCO 3DS Authentication Decoding

Tags: encryption, authentication, pci-dss

I bumped across a request via Traffic analysis through Burp Suite Proxy & it looked like a 3DS Authentication.

Sample below:

[image: 3ds_auth]

My question was if this authentication could be intercepted, decoded or tampered with using any attack vectors such as *CSRF*, *MiTM* or otherwise. Are there any attack vectors that had been successfully proven, yet?

Comment: I take it that the 3ds tag you created were refering to 3-D Secure? I renamed it to make it clearer. Please let me know if I misunderstood something here.

Comment: It's 3D encypt (not encode {most confuse this one}). Vendor - EvCOM.